# Why electron spin align to the direction of magnetic fields?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

If we consider localized and unpaired spins in a condensed matter system, the spins align to the direction of applied magnetic fields. We can calculate the magnetization by considering canonical ensemble, giving the field dependence of the Brillouin function.

However, in quantum mechanics (or in the Lamor precession), the spin only precesses around the z-axis (the direction of applied magnetic fields), and the z-component of spin is conserved.

I wonder any theory to describe the dynamics of spin aligning to the direction of magnetic fields. If there is it, I also wonder about the time scale of the spin aligning.

Comment: The spin results in a magnetic moment which interacts with the magnetic field

Comment: This may help - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)